# Sublime Text 2 & PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, sublimetext2

When running a python script on Sublime Text 2 (OSX), the python interpreter works (using Enthought Python Distribution) but not my own PYTHONPATH. Here's what the Python.sublime-build file looks like at the moment:

```
{
"path": "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/",
"cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

How can I add the PYTHONPATH to this file correctly? I know that the PYTHONPATH is not being picked up by Sublime Text 2, since some of my custom packages cannot be imported. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup was correct from above, but my system has to be restarted. Once that was done everything was working.

Answer (score 13):

I'm working with SublimeText2 build 2202 (I have a license and I can download all the "nightly" releases) and I add an "env" attribute to the builder.

For example:

```
{
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/",
    "cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
    "env":
    {
        "PYTHONPATH": "path/to/a/folder:path/to/another/folder",
    },    
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Whatever values you set in this way will be prepended to the PYTHONPATH that Sublime sees.

Your problem was a little different, but I thought that knowing this could be helpful.

Comment: Helped me figure out how to unbork my D language build, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

In my mac, I need to add a comma after the back brace of "env"

```
{
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/",
    "cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
    "env":
    {
        "PYTHONPATH": "path/to/a/folder:path/to/another/folder",
    },    
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```