# PYTHONPATH in the python process of Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I tried to get PYTHONPATH in the python process (ex. the console or some packages ) of Sublime Text 2 running "os.environ.get('pythonpath')", but it's empty. It seems not to import only PYTHONPATH from system environment variables. Other variables were imported.

If editing "Python.sublime-build", variables was not imported.

Can I get PYTHONPATH in the process?

Comment: Where do you need to change the PYTHONPATH?  Is this in a module you are writing for Sublime, or a test that you are running using the build command from sublime?

Comment: It's in a module. When a subprocess is created in a module (ex. Terminal Package), I expect PYTHONPATH imported, but not.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  In that case, the build system is not used.  You should check out ["Directing Packages to the correct python installation"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10712390/1309332) or ["Change python interpreter"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11313131/1309332)

Comment: I have read both, then it seems that there is no way to set PYTHONPATH to all modules in Sublime Text2 and I should set each. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `env` option in your custom Python build system ([documented here](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#options)).  Basically, you'll want something like this:

```
"env": {
        "PYTHONPATH":"/my/custom/modules"
       }
```

Make sure if you are overriding the default Python build rule that you do it in the User folder so that your customization will persist through upgrades.

Comment: Basically the same as [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11120411/1309332)

Comment: What I concerned is not build system, but python package system. Even if putting 'env' to Python.sublime-build, it's no available from package process?